# Exponential of linear operators and its relation to its operator norm

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, normed-spaces, exponential-function, banach-spaces

Suppose $E$ is a Banach space over $\mathbb{K}\,\, (\mathbb{R} \,\,\text{or}\,\, \mathbb{C})$, $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, and $C$ is a closed, convex subset of $E$. We define the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm) here on $\mathcal{L}(E)$. Show that these two are equivalent:

1. $\mathrm{e}^{tA}\subset C, \forall t\in\mathbb{R}$.
2. $(\lambda-A)^{-1}C\subset C$, for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(\lambda)>\Vert A\Vert$.

I currently don't have any clues to this problem (I tried the taylor expansion of $\mathrm{exp}$, but I got it very complicated and failed), and hope that someone can help solve this problem and it would be appreciated if a more intuitive or straightfoward outlook of this problem is presented.

Comment: You have not said what $C$ is.